# Limit internet access for an app for an specific network

Tags: network, data-transfer

Can I deny Internet access to Transmission.app if the Mac is connected to a mobile network (defined by name) but allow Internet access when connected to a home network?

Comment: You *may* be able to do that with Little Snitch

Comment: I think that Little Snitch profiles might do what you want https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch5/adv-profiles

Comment: Could you clarify how you get your mobile network? Either through an USB connection, a Bluetooth or a Wi-Fi connection to your iPhone.

I imagine your home network is through Wi-Fi.